# Spotify API-Net ResumePlayback - Error With Code Example From Documentation

Tags: spotify, spotify-desktop

The documentation at Spotiy API_NET for [ResumePlayback](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET/blob/master/SpotifyAPI.Docs/docs/SpotifyWebAPI/player.md)

gives the following example:

```
ErrorResponse error = _spotify.ResumePlayback(uris: new List<string> { "spotify:track:4iV5W9uYEdYUVa79Axb7Rh" });
```

When I try that code in C#, I get the following code error which prevents me building:

> Error  CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'SpotifyWebAPI.ResumePlayback(string, string, List, int?)' and 'SpotifyWebAPI.ResumePlayback(string, string, List, string)'
>   Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

Also, what is the simplest way to simply resume the existing player at the point where it was paused?

## Edit

@rene answered the first part of my question.

In regard to the second part, how to resume the existing player at the point where it was paused, I got the answer through the library's Github site, it's simply:

```
_spotify.ResumePlayback(offset: "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ResumePlayback](https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET/blob/master/SpotifyAPI/Web/SpotifyWebAPI.cs) method has two overloads that take these parameters:

```
ErrorResponse ResumePlayback(string deviceId = "", 
                            string contextUri = "", 
                            List<string> uris = null,
                            int? offset = null)
```

and

```
ErrorResponse ResumePlayback(string deviceId = "", 
                             string contextUri = "", 
                             List<string> uris = null,
                             string offset = "")
```

When the compiler comes across this line

```
ErrorResponse error = _spotify.ResumePlayback(
                            uris: new List<string> { "spotify:track:4iV5W9uYEdYUVa79Axb7Rh" });
```

it has to decide which ResumePlayback it is going to call and it doesn't want to take a guess or roll a dice.

It looks at which parameters are going to be provided and you only give it `uris` (that is the third parameter). It will assume the defaults for the other parameters. For both methods these defaults (null for strings or for the Nullable<int> (int?)) apply so the compiler can't decide which method it should bind to. It shows you an error.

Provide more parameters so the compiler can pick an unique overload.

```
ErrorResponse error = _spotify.ResumePlayback(
                            uris: new List<string> { "spotify:track:4iV5W9uYEdYUVa79Axb7Rh" }
                            , 
                            offset: 0
                       );
```

Adding that named parameter `offset` and setting it to the `int` value of 0 is enough for the compiler to pick this overload to bind to:

```
ResumePlayback(string deviceId, string contextUri, List<string> uris, int? offset)
```

Comment: OK, I understand that but I thought that the final offset parameter is also optional; Obviously, there is an error in the supplied example in the documentation .